# How to have fade in and fade out between multi widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a bottom navigation bar with 5 items and for each widget I should load some data from server , I want to have fade in and fade out between items but I don't know how? , because I think items are not a new pages that I implement route fade transitions.
also I defined a futureBuilder for each Items to load it's data
It's possible to do sth in futureBuilder's ConnectionState.waiting but it doesn't have fade transition and the transition is jumping
also i check interet connection with connectivity plugin

I get into trouble to handle them because I am almost new to flutter !

and i am wonder to know what is the most powerful way to handle it.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `AnimatedSwitcher` is what you are looking for, it adds an implicit animation to its child, so that whenever you call `setState()` to change its child, it automatically starts a fade-in/fade-out animation between them. Check out this video from the Widget of the Week series:

[AnimatedSwitcher from Widget of the Week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W7POjFb88g)

Another possibility is `AnimatedOpacity`, that can achieve a similar behaviour by changing its child's opacity. Here is a reference to the documentation on `AnimatedOpacity` widget:

[AnimatedOpacity from Flutter dev documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedOpacity-class.html)

Comment: thanks , this widget solve the transition problem , also do you have any idea to change UI from ConnectionState.waiting witch contain a circleProgressIndecator to ConnectionState.done ?

Comment: or is there any widget  like futureBuilder to have same behavior for loading data and show the UI based on state of loading data but with nice animation?because I want to show fade Transition twice:   1-change of widget    2-loading data

Comment: I suspect that `StreamBuilder` is what you are looking for. You will need to change your connection states, that are probably built around `Future`, and re-build them around `Stream`, that will let you listen to changes on network data. `StreamBuilder` will let you react to changes in your `Stream` and update your UI based on them. Here is a [Widget of the Week video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkKEWHfy99Y) about `StreamBuilder` that you might find useful. However, I recommend you mark this question as solved by my answer and open another question, so people will find the topic easily.

Answer (score 4):

I know that's a really old question, but I solved using something like that:

```
  Widget dynWidget = CircularProgressIndicator();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            dynWidget = Text('Content loaded!');
          }
          return AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1), child: dynWidget);
        });
  }
```